# CiviCRM email related issue

Tags: civimail, email, flexmailer

I am working with CiviCRM and we have an issue with outbound emails.

From what we can see the emails coming through contain both text/plain and text/html and the email clients are not parsing them correctly.

This is an example of what the outlook displays when receiving a message.

```
--=_3c119f906f3141711ca80a03ffbefc9b
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Test

--=_3c119f906f3141711ca80a03ffbefc9b
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Test

--=_3c119f906f3141711ca80a03ffbefc9b--
```

We are not familiar with CiviCRM and we are just using mail() as the provider.

We are assuming it is likely a broken header but within the plethora of settings nothing seems to affect the format.

If it helps under extensions we can see that CiviMail (v5.66.0) is enabled and there is also  FlexMailer (v5.66.0) enabled.

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: In Outlook you should be able to "View Source" to see the full raw message including the headers.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever get it resolved?