# HTML and EMAIL content and no Graphics or formatting in emails

Tags: civimail

Recently upgraded to 5.66 and now Civimail sends an email with the text and html content in the email, also any graphics not shown. Note the email address is also odd. Below is a copy of the email as it arrived in the inbox. Looks perfect in the Ckeditor.

viz:>>>> start of email
b.3079.78886.e06a54f96fd8d0f9@aaaa.org

13:00 (4 hours ago)

to me
--=_ca63d17a869f264c3d3540d004645f59
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8WILLIAMSTOWN

my name..

WILLIAMSTOWN ABC

Dear Ian,

test

My Name

Williamstown ABC

To unsubscribe: Unsubscribe [1]

_ Powered by Civicrm_

### Links:

[1] https://aaaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=3079&qid=78886&h=e06a54f96fd8d0f9

--=_ca63d17a869f264c3d3540d004645f59
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

AAA Victoria

```
                    <h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:#ffffff;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Williamstown ABC</span></span></h1>
                    </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Dear Ian,

test

My Name

Williamstown SEC

To unsubscribe: [Unsubscribe](https://aaaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=3079&qid=78886&h=e06a54f96dfd8d0f9) 

 *Powered by Civicrm*

--=_ca63d17a869f264c3d3540d004645f59--

> > > > > > end of email

I did have an error about tokens in a template ("Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (off-line)") which i fixed by removing some lines but I do not think this has anything to do with emailing.
I have upgraded drupal from 7.94 (23/01/23) to 7.98 (22/10/23) and Civicrm from 5.46.2 to 5.66 (22/10/23) and PHP from 7.4 (3/3/22) to PHP 8.1 (23/10/23).

FULL EMAIL - ONLY CHANGED URL >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
Received: by 2002:a05:7208:d046:b0:6f:1b0b:ec43 with SMTP id y6csp795300rba;
        Thu, 26 Oct 2023 19:14:35 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IGFE9zZ0UzdR2hWAWbe5wLa9/FXr7L7nIkLZQk74Pcv3OGflG+oQiQ+XgoENdvJ4mdWS5Os
X-Received: by 2002:a17:902:ed13:b0:1c6:294c:f89c with SMTP id b19-20020a170902ed1300b001c6294cf89cmr1255621pld.63.1698372875397;
        Thu, 26 Oct 2023 19:14:35 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1698372875; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=YNO9v4KuL6bS+Uv0rC6ensv3mscivhwV54eH4365DEmNfmIH5YKSuiJNtRRADgEkrG
         iWjIEJd4aKAL5JdDipK9XqFek0H+N0ICKSdmEEr+A3fPKxonc3ySGqXvJrYcup5oveU6
         MmVGGMUsbhn0tzwpqYC5JIPRmT0o1hggMWLCRdkbb2FPTBXDc6iVVOWEk/B1rsdDd6Y8
         Twi5DCcdQPJXGD9SfaZkhMsWNqJiUJ5Z6QB6IjpogDDZXhaIK/YD+h8otQrJ6HZRvgn8
         sXTqS3hoDTKn0BjoLXe+0s2G0SCVDjy7DnfuUlYE6Vo1iNKA8rRETt8vow2Jj7FRr5/a
         ugJQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:from:message-id:mime-version:subject:to:dkim-signature;
        bh=n3hoZgLMtpCH667iF67ZF+zS2h7fgvrEaqE6MAw3Zm0=;
        fh=drJV50q+9Zk9lNqEZoeH10Cz6R3jYl/H2elpBjvjCww=;
        b=mZUa69DzrCLcEuk7GfO8MQu+i+BpfYFlCGrAY2LkzmujQovBolaImcWwfK+TUfjTit
         wB1U+MdWPkZuFV9ULwbgjauYDSsXSmKiANDpBhR8dSSTUurdflDZV62JYQ/RTUq+8DXB
         ujMd8Znvxyd9ktbByUyG8wYbviAkaGpOeEZc4du/zlqUFM/sCy+qn1xWc7pNoE77euM4
         VjkYOEvsNTNt1aTGYU6j/Mgv9wAfFyM3KcKnjdTFGlwbAGsydHEiBPBbkkls0MIhz249
         giE3iXUS7y1+vtpLPFVkRwydWPWX32cp3ygAQFNqGYHfxLb3wDZudsE0niV/3NcimzI6
         7xGw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@aaa.org header.s=default header.b=UA+04yfg;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org designates 35.89.44.34 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org
Return-Path: <b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org>
Received: from omta35.uswest2.a.cloudfilter.net (omta35.uswest2.a.cloudfilter.net. [35.89.44.34])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id d5-20020a170903230500b001bc079974dbsi464704plh.355.2023.10.26.19.14.34
        for <aaa@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 26 Oct 2023 19:14:34 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org designates 35.89.44.34 as permitted sender) client-ip=35.89.44.34;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@aaa.org header.s=default header.b=UA+04yfg;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org designates 35.89.44.34 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org
Received: from eig-obgw-6003a.ext.cloudfilter.net ([10.0.30.151]) by cmsmtp with ESMTPS id wAA0qrs4EhqFdwCMsqJ1SF; Fri, 27 Oct 2023 02:14:34 +0000
Received: from harrier.websitewelcome.com ([192.185.83.107]) by cmsmtp with ESMTPS id wCMqqQSVpRqxCwCMrqJO8g; Fri, 27 Oct 2023 02:14:33 +0000
X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.4 cv=IY2U5Ema c=1 sm=1 tr=0 ts=653b1d09 a=PEXN0kqERGfpDbwOsM9Lrw==:117 a=OWjo9vPv0XrRhIrVQ50Ab3nP57M=:19 a=dLZJa+xiwSxG16/P+YVxDGlgEgI=:19 a=dXCnJTF15noA:10 a=bhdUkHdE2iEA:10 a=O4E_PBewnzIA:10 a=4v_fjtIuAAAA:8 a=WpWwP1NjkZ-qq9kLDQ0A:9 a=hhnteAknvzHUoGrS:21 a=yQD-zf_IIDVdLvJsLJma:22 a=G0u7fxU7sV0lX6SvgOtL:22
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=aaa.org ; s=default; h=Date:From:Message-Id:MIME-Version:Subject:To:Sender:Reply-To: Cc:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:Content-Description: Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID: In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe: List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive; bh=n3hoZgLMtpCH667iF67ZF+zS2h7fgvrEaqE6MAw3Zm0=; b=UA+04yfgivrbar/fXa7JQ11fRD J3mb0Db569O4stBlG60JYbpHxhLM/LLq+qdDCFJfU8up3qpMcwin95a9Uu8MvdrpHORmgoXZwI9J4 a3XdrvJDm8K1VHGM2kKPoVF5HpD8KLDFtmvjOHB+Mi/w+cESBUATRomPXnxtFSUso2THN3t1BWqvz H91zF/qoSPD+4QHJ2kGiN7jHsMmlor66Mk9hay6Y+Sn9A68y+0TA8OEQVnPcqKVdRgdtAh4EduWyW gokPwViUluqh5B89Mj7BKPTJfHKlZKP2BPopFlIL+B+ZMVk9LJrRfU8jGgPtNxBvKUj6xFfCVIrK0 ohIFxQKw==;
Received: from aaa by harrier.websitewelcome.com with local (Exim 4.96.2) (envelope-from <b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org>) id 1qwCMq-000FJJ-29 for aaa@gmail.com; Thu, 26 Oct 2023 21:14:32 -0500
To: <aaa@gmail.com>
Subject: [CiviMail Draft] Williamstown Liberals SEC Newsletter
X-PHP-Script: aaa.org/drupal/index.php for 101.181.98.11 X-PHP-Originating-Script: 5705:mail.php
MIME-Version: 1.0 List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:u.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org> Precedence: bulk job_id: 3086 From: "Liberals" <liberals@aaa.org> Return-Path: b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org X-CiviMail-Bounce: b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary="=_d02e2e40878c24e4a573b81e90d7d140" Date: Fri, 27 Oct 2023 13:14:32 +1100
Message-Id: <E1qwCMq-000FJJ-29@harrier.websitewelcome.com>
From: b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org
Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2023 21:14:32 -0500
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - harrier.websitewelcome.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [5705 32008] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - aaa.org
X-BWhitelist: no
X-Source-IP: 
X-Source-L: No
X-Exim-ID: 1qwCMq-000FJJ-29
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: aaa.org:/public_html/drupal
X-Source-Sender: 
X-Source-Auth: aaa
X-Email-Count: 1
X-Org: HG=hgreseller;ORG=hostgator;
X-Source-Cap: bGlid2VzdDtncm5sZ2h0O2hhcnJpZXIud2Vic2l0ZXdlbGNvbWUuY29t
X-Local-Domain: yes
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4xfC3O35AjnQHks5YDqYCx4yYlUfmnBfC1wgcmB6zEVaMfyvNxFsrKq67nuHAvlRnigakg1LZ+i/Pj5biWLJZPmf5OXxpsKewS9ew1ICjVDebG3qVpto/d CLmkYoa5CsPQig5frsRj/am0ItLsX2i5k7bPDrg1AqFV0Y2YE26jtJo+gXeibxP+HJHF86jD0POH1Cwn8yHoprczDtGwOyFcZo82go6yJ/+KIw+2aLjoO90o uLXYKzknE82xnSeIVHwJBg==

--=_d02e2e40878c24e4a573b81e90d7d140
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

aaa OF VICTORIA

WILLIAMSTOWN SEC

 

Dear ,

 

 

Ian Hocking

Williamstown SEC

 
To unsubscribe: Unsubscribe [1] 

_ Powered by Civicrm_

Links:
------
[1] https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=3086&qid=78893&h=b6ac1c49b1035d76

--=_d02e2e40878c24e4a573b81e90d7d140
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="#ccc" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; background-color: white;"><img alt="" src="http://aaa.org/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/LiberalLogo_Clear.png" style="width: 150px; height: 119px;" /></td>
            <td style="text-align: left; background-color: rgb(6, 120, 201);">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:#ffffff;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">aaa of Victoria</span></span></h1>

            <h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:#ffffff;"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Williamstown SEC</span></span></h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><span style="font-size:14px;">Dear&nbsp;,</span></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Ian Hocking</p>

<p>Williamstown SEC</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
To unsubscribe: <a href="https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&amp;jid=3086&amp;qid=78893&amp;h=b6ac1c49b1035d76">Unsubscribe</a> <br/>
<br/>
<font color="maroon"><i> Powered by Civicrm</i>
<img src="https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/open?qid=78893" width='1' height='1' alt='' border='0'>
--=_d02e2e40878c24e4a573b81e90d7d140--
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

With PHP 7.4

```
Original message
Message ID  <E1qwbOw-001l3z-0v@harrier.websitewelcome.com>
Created on: 28 October 2023 at 15:58 (Delivered after 2 seconds)
From:   Liberals <liberals@aaa.org>
To: aaa@gmail.com
Subject:    [CiviMail Draft] Last chance to reserve your spot: Coffee & chat with Jim
SPF:    PASS with IP 44.202.169.32 Learn more
DKIM:   'PASS' with domain aaa.org Learn more


Download original
Copy to clipboard

Delivered-To: aaa@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a05:7208:55a9:b0:6f:1b0b:ec43 with SMTP id bi41csp320852rbb;
        Fri, 27 Oct 2023 21:58:25 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IFYwYanSymosVxaU8NOx58Vw6wzV8RCdZVCgDe8/4D2WUbCbtx70wW4OANDOii4r2dR176y
X-Received: by 2002:a05:620a:6017:b0:76e:ffaa:a816 with SMTP id dw23-20020a05620a601700b0076effaaa816mr4480639qkb.75.1698469104834;
        Fri, 27 Oct 2023 21:58:24 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1698469104; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=ALc8zdz0uK3//M9Jqmtz7mFKyK1Y8ANGwLQ8oAWofFpawjab7kMZQ4JNwc7x/5xJoZ
         UoU5SC2PkVZmW5fPEFWGJxn7F3BakFFf6iMpGL7V7N5t3cKFYtzwOVfIT94WPOtT2+34
         qNUqx8ZZuKPGGHhk/2ni36+CBYeKTrX0avLYLgZwvhIhZi33AJzWpDOVNueNMPRUkJfB
         4Dp7ET/gKMSeXeqfxpirx92CG82yIw//8SVYmzNcrer1zfcRHI7ulmpX0dvPXcedHTut
         qIew3Mrxt+dbFW2Jc4kvDR5QIDtRUTtMIc6iOAvSvC34CTMadtV/Sf19eZ+YH38BE+bV
         A8bQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=message-id:date:from:job_id:precedence:list-unsubscribe
         :mime-version:subject:to:dkim-signature;
        bh=w2/NrMu6sILn0cxnSxQ/HpRcwQl/BglztCKHEMIcflI=;
        fh=drJV50q+9Zk9lNqEZoeH10Cz6R3jYl/H2elpBjvjCww=;
        b=lpUWQt2a/0Tn37/DnU7346DRgBywxzJPOcIN/9P+oCgVqNsY4er+YUmrgifw00I/3q
         FbbFb5N75YD8eprOYmWarEYv9UnNrD6iZxvgcVAvdKwy7IQtemXJwO8UgaHTXzFKOY6m
         SBAkqPhXV9kydDsg4xEAI1JOXlJKsdjwREUy+L/W77qmA9mKTT8j8CAlWd3YMsTT75/Q
         vFPb5yb/TG15KQ67WmGnW6mM8o7qCpnna1VhPAKeBXQw0X2UKUstfNaKKqtrZXoVYV9Y
         pj2UySXFUQXDLOj/IvIH7AUvNtwZ35GWw+/fo2ShboWxU7Ir3YrLMNLXOpTIGpJXjPqb
         CwEQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@aaa.org header.s=default header.b=UaUpCfaE;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of b.3092.78899.1aff3f44f6650f6b@aaa.org designates 44.202.169.32 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=b.3092.78899.1aff3f44f6650f6b@aaa.org
Return-Path: <b.3092.78899.1aff3f44f6650f6b@aaa.org>
Received: from omta033.useast.a.cloudfilter.net (omta033.useast.a.cloudfilter.net. [44.202.169.32])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id f27-20020a05620a15bb00b00779e70e2777si1650691qkk.519.2023.10.27.21.58.24
        for <aaa@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 27 Oct 2023 21:58:24 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of b.3092.78899.1aff3f44f6650f6b@aaa.org designates 44.202.169.32 as permitted sender) client-ip=44.202.169.32;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@aaa.org header.s=default header.b=UaUpCfaE;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of b.3092.78899.1aff3f44f6650f6b@aaa.org designates 44.202.169.32 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=b.3092.78899.1aff3f44f6650f6b@aaa.org
Received: from eig-obgw-6009a.ext.cloudfilter.net ([10.0.30.184]) by cmsmtp with ESMTPS id wMRaqVibmjtZ3wbOyqM720; Sat, 28 Oct 2023 04:58:25 +0000
Received: from harrier.websitewelcome.com ([192.185.83.107]) by cmsmtp with ESMTPS id wbOwq6McgOk5SwbOxquKq1; Sat, 28 Oct 2023 04:58:23 +0000
X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.4 cv=E+DeGIRl c=1 sm=1 tr=0 ts=653c94ef a=PEXN0kqERGfpDbwOsM9Lrw==:117 a=OWjo9vPv0XrRhIrVQ50Ab3nP57M=:19 a=dLZJa+xiwSxG16/P+YVxDGlgEgI=:19 a=-S1hUXpT4R_DRAgF:21 a=dXCnJTF15noA:10 a=bhdUkHdE2iEA:10 a=O4E_PBewnzIA:10 a=4v_fjtIuAAAA:8 a=YpcfGz_jEuMbHcW-mY0A:9 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 a=okE-M7gcAAAA:8 a=y5Oy8Mt9Lh3VICWxy-sA:9 a=oC8CuAte2NgTU6n1:21 a=yQD-zf_IIDVdLvJsLJma:22 a=G0u7fxU7sV0lX6SvgOtL:22 a=No-rZXW96PReiIdYbifg:22 a=nb-ZEjrkFBj5XG7Gp5Uu:22
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=aaa.org ; s=default; h=Message-Id:Date:Content-Type:From:List-Unsubscribe: MIME-Version:Subject:To:Sender:Reply-To:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding: Content-ID:Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender: Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id: List-Help:List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive; bh=w2/NrMu6sILn0cxnSxQ/HpRcwQl/BglztCKHEMIcflI=; b=UaUpCfaEfl7Xj4qC/HzfdVa5Aa XXTkBmasnxJOq/FNX5YZJP+rqzdq7DJwLMXc7SGxLr8VQecW4s/640LWAhB8nts44NdJl/hh612lt CWnDGxZGaZr2MpHVnzjiGjvXnYY2Grciisib2VwODQohh3nRi0SPk9qNlQNRfOkA7qnXBzmW/qOgm Gm2OhAhUuXQpHiP/A8nTAqIlEadzTN/QU9uB3O/q+CalFlQS4avbCwNJavWhkL4WWQuqI8g387LHV J2PMeh/1jFgAro8/GBYah8zQvTXsp4oDzJOGt4oYHDy3iQcCvpnfFucknAhaTAsY953YX0v+OqMqa ejJH1CQg==;
Received: from aaa by harrier.websitewelcome.com with local (Exim 4.96.2) (envelope-from <b.3092.78899.1aff3f44f6650f6b@aaa.org>) id 1qwbOw-001l3z-0v for aaa@gmail.com; Fri, 27 Oct 2023 23:58:22 -0500
To: <aaa@gmail.com>
Subject: [CiviMail Draft] Last chance to reserve your spot: Coffee & chat with
  Jim
X-PHP-Script: aaa.org/drupal/index.php for 101.181.98.11
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 5705:mail.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:u.3092.78899.1aff3f44f6650f6b@aaa.org>
Precedence: bulk
job_id: 3092
From: Liberals <liberals@aaa.org>
X-CiviMail-Bounce: b.3092.78899.1aff3f44f6650f6b@aaa.org
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=_b8812c2ba5e87465f331ccc26b63babe"
Date: Sat, 28 Oct 2023 15:58:22 +1100
Message-Id: <E1qwbOw-001l3z-0v@harrier.websitewelcome.com>
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - harrier.websitewelcome.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [5705 32008] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - aaa.org
X-BWhitelist: no
X-Source-IP: 
X-Source-L: No
X-Exim-ID: 1qwbOw-001l3z-0v
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: aaa.org:/public_html/drupal
X-Source-Sender: 
X-Source-Auth: aaa
X-Email-Count: 6
X-Org: HG=hgreseller;ORG=hostgator;
X-Source-Cap: bGlid2VzdDtncm5sZ2h0O2hhcnJpZXIud2Vic2l0ZXdlbGNvbWUuY29t
X-Local-Domain: yes
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4xfJ9XniiFUdwS4FiS6jZS0RSFTCbMg9bIEXRRZlYCfAnYnrxnQC7qY2az/Iv2bg8biN7nI3MQL63xhyln8kK17rplxDA9NT2Dq7swoBLlx+f04erwkQPJ j6pBotjDkEdju1LNcELLAkcSYiJfcNzoXYpK559Cy3TwDhRmNn0cQ+83B5EgA8dv9g6CMRIPy+sUXruAeod/gtDPd3lXj5GO5RVSWmwJw5+XM6yQYw5KF2MT 0AHFA8cTKW5G4eMt8ZVIRQ==

--=_b8812c2ba5e87465f331ccc26b63babe
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

DON'T MISS OUR COFFEE AND CHAT WITH Jim
Join Jim for the first of the 'coffee and chat' series hosted
by Gellibrand FEC, Williamstown SEC, and Williamstown Branch.

Time/date: 10-11:30AM, SATURDAY 28TH OCTOBER

Location: WILLIAMSTOWN COMMUNITY & EDUCATION CENTRE, 14 THOMPSON STREET,
WILLIAMSTOWN

Jim will have an open discussion with us about the policy direction and other topics of interest to members.

The ticket price of $5 includes coffee.

BOOK YOUR PLACE NOW AT: https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/url?u=551&qid=78899 [1]

         

 To unsubscribe: Unsubscribe [2] 

_ Powered by Civicrm_

Links:
------
[1] https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/url?u=551&qid=78899
[2] https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=3092&qid=78899&h=1aff3f44f6650f6b

--=_b8812c2ba5e87465f331ccc26b63babe
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p><strong><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Don&#39;t miss our coffee and chat with Jim</span></span></strong></p>

            <p>Jim for the first of the &#39;coffee and chat&#39; series hosted by <u>Gellibrand FEC,</u> <u>Williamstown SEC</u>, and <u>Williamstown Branch</u>.<br />
            <br />
            Time/date: <strong>10-11:30am, Saturday 28th October</strong></p>

            <p>Location: <strong>Williamstown Community &amp; Education Centre</strong>, <strong>14 Thompson Street, Williamstown</strong></p>

            <p>Jim will have an open discussion with us about the Federal Liberal Party&#39;s policy direction and other topics of interest to members.<br />
            <br />
            The ticket price of $5 includes coffee.</p>

            <p><strong>Book your place now at</strong>:&nbsp;<a href="https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/url?u=551&amp;qid=78899" rel='nofollow'>https://www.trybooking.com/CLOUU</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
To unsubscribe: <a href="https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&amp;jid=3092&amp;qid=78899&amp;h=1aff3f44f6650f6b">Unsubscribe</a> <br/>
<br/>
<font color="maroon"><i> Powered by Civicrm</i>
<img src="https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/open?qid=78899" width='1' height='1' alt='' border='0'>
--=_b8812c2ba5e87465f331ccc26b63babe--
```

With PHP 8.2

```
Message ID  <E1qwbNE-001kWw-1D@harrier.websitewelcome.com>
Created on: 28 October 2023 at 15:56 (Delivered after 2 seconds)
From:   b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org
To: aaa@gmail.com
Subject:    [CiviMail Draft] Last chance to reserve your spot: Coffee & chat with Jim
SPF:    PASS with IP 44.202.169.34 Learn more
DKIM:   'PASS' with domain aaa.org Learn more


Download original
Copy to clipboard

Delivered-To: aaa@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a05:7208:55a9:b0:6f:1b0b:ec43 with SMTP id bi41csp320489rbb;
        Fri, 27 Oct 2023 21:56:38 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGHT+IHWlixturqe0X/mDxjKoyJ7LeQ6YF+3GJ2Z6Y6QPm7uXwID9GYwkH9WOtX55ZD53Lk/QWmm
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6214:19c3:b0:65b:fa3:4a01 with SMTP id j3-20020a05621419c300b0065b0fa34a01mr5748005qvc.62.1698468998462;
        Fri, 27 Oct 2023 21:56:38 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1698468998; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=jaUnzIV1F9jnOCGl9UaxobTQSUOLVoUp6YwS+d0jDiIcwOLZfjeVbUDlnayJGkXaOB
         pMFuTc/qxYLt114IRHxj4zrCQSWAFSC9X/ZIj1jvAc6MiblD0GLRF6Bpy1Qg8F+x80U5
         dSEwTkKYafsajMI5DJlGE3xaulQXvGT5ykdeHsIvLFesEcTfhsBveseeY8h6+gXqeFET
         HB+VDnGc1qxFgsSfG+CkU4AdetZjX+jNpfIHPHdpNzR2bfQaOLXudX5UwF9w6zIG5nvD
         d+sXa4Ydq/LGSq1pqzkWc3bWNYLiaOkY6x9u6XUVUGBs9N+7QWFsjrcd/iBun4M1u3U5
         3n2Q==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=date:from:message-id:mime-version:subject:to:dkim-signature;
        bh=53OKc6ZumZZVTfZ8NWUhigUiMUEBwSNavJS671Ukom8=;
        fh=drJV50q+9Zk9lNqEZoeH10Cz6R3jYl/H2elpBjvjCww=;
        b=BoJpPb5xqNEY8DBHdB9nu4vssVesPex5MoxUDnp4l1ggmIIemPmI6yBHlpClHBjseJ
         OnXsUEK3/wz5qqFYssnzIdd3j6hbfRC0xPPcrlIBDOJqcBRvgrTxltJtHf9gpfj8cPqO
         vnmo6+2i2iTFvuN+Tp/0KFWIZACuhEQClZeZXedcDwYbtTlxAZYISWtRWmkOISbfu19D
         2CG8y/lIyd+B4g2e/v4mVLljfhwuhFB8jtLPuO4TBn3/r11ybuHQF3wUk98MKOCqqSy8
         Z/vcoN8YhwmCjm7oiMQc47kt4zrSCLKiEcEjkDEZwrFOrGbWm7tVPtU8xmsQncLhUOSx
         IUjA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@aaa.org header.s=default header.b=pMr+hS2q;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org designates 44.202.169.34 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org
Return-Path: <b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org>
Received: from omta035.useast.a.cloudfilter.net (omta035.useast.a.cloudfilter.net. [44.202.169.34])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id h9-20020ac87d49000000b00419674b991asi1771935qtb.505.2023.10.27.21.56.38
        for <aaa@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 27 Oct 2023 21:56:38 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org designates 44.202.169.34 as permitted sender) client-ip=44.202.169.34;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@aaa.org header.s=default header.b=pMr+hS2q;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org designates 44.202.169.34 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org
Received: from eig-obgw-6010a.ext.cloudfilter.net ([10.0.30.248]) by cmsmtp with ESMTPS id wPlrqbCxZgpyEwbNFq6NOg; Sat, 28 Oct 2023 04:56:37 +0000
Received: from harrier.websitewelcome.com ([192.185.83.107]) by cmsmtp with ESMTPS id wbNEqFF6gruMPwbNFq4RON; Sat, 28 Oct 2023 04:56:37 +0000
X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.4 cv=ZNHEJF3b c=1 sm=1 tr=0 ts=653c9485 a=PEXN0kqERGfpDbwOsM9Lrw==:117 a=OWjo9vPv0XrRhIrVQ50Ab3nP57M=:19 a=dLZJa+xiwSxG16/P+YVxDGlgEgI=:19 a=-S1hUXpT4R_DRAgF:21 a=dXCnJTF15noA:10 a=bhdUkHdE2iEA:10 a=O4E_PBewnzIA:10 a=4v_fjtIuAAAA:8 a=okE-M7gcAAAA:8 a=mnKYI0rjSfJg827Tvb8A:9 a=oC8CuAte2NgTU6n1:21 a=yQD-zf_IIDVdLvJsLJma:22 a=G0u7fxU7sV0lX6SvgOtL:22 a=No-rZXW96PReiIdYbifg:22 a=nb-ZEjrkFBj5XG7Gp5Uu:22
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=aaa.org ; s=default; h=Date:From:Message-Id:MIME-Version:Subject:To:Sender:Reply-To: Cc:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:Content-Description: Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID: In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe: List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive; bh=53OKc6ZumZZVTfZ8NWUhigUiMUEBwSNavJS671Ukom8=; b=pMr+hS2qbCxjOVjz/qxEyfNjag 8zuAn1u0kEb2N++O8c7mbblFR0Re7RlZ0tBJm0YEauxNpTQ6C2wytWzhSN183OymibJtv6368hieS UBpkLIvLnuhf7Rk1UCI7W51Hm8FiLWwdIyhjilv7sNScg5kLUMXp6O90s4MsBID7XZeh1TkLcGGQt Tmx118OfvcRrP1Pd3SGW9S9eFGtrw1SCTg4aCnH9RZg50X8gPRsSm6cmkr7cmG7JJPPFHHP1zkgvj Tu1xAKdm4Cy28eYVFfo/u7AKMlrIwWj3IebeCAGoWpV5KlRmmh5c5qylg8985Obe0tsy3JLk4NwVd oapq9V2g==;
Received: from aaa by harrier.websitewelcome.com with local (Exim 4.96.2) (envelope-from <b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org>) id 1qwbNE-001kWw-1D for aaa@gmail.com; Fri, 27 Oct 2023 23:56:36 -0500
To: <aaa@gmail.com>
Subject: [CiviMail Draft] Last chance to reserve your spot: Coffee & chat with
  Jim
X-PHP-Script: aaa.org/drupal/index.php for 101.181.98.11 X-PHP-Originating-Script: 5705:mail.php
MIME-Version: 1.0 List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:u.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org> Precedence: bulk job_id: 3091 From: "Liberals" <liberals@aaa.org> Return-Path: b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org X-CiviMail-Bounce: b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary="=_a6836d14709272c4387b47be6f69b83e" Date: Sat, 28 Oct 2023 15:56:36 +1100
Message-Id: <E1qwbNE-001kWw-1D@harrier.websitewelcome.com>
From: b.3091.78898.3f5397f6454f5d1e@aaa.org
Date: Fri, 27 Oct 2023 23:56:36 -0500
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - harrier.websitewelcome.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [5705 32008] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - aaa.org
X-BWhitelist: no
X-Source-IP: 
X-Source-L: No
X-Exim-ID: 1qwbNE-001kWw-1D
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: aaa.org:/public_html/drupal
X-Source-Sender: 
X-Source-Auth: aaa
X-Email-Count: 5
X-Org: HG=hgreseller;ORG=hostgator;
X-Source-Cap: bGlid2VzdDtncm5sZ2h0O2hhcnJpZXIud2Vic2l0ZXdlbGNvbWUuY29t
X-Local-Domain: yes
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4xfKU9cRZu++gtUj0fZQT+9FKtRohKGuxbNsk5F24q+C5LW7U2zXpz2N9lfzHZx3COvZg6Q/7z0HroDSQgsINtS1GMfF0brjwT6d7H+RWuJJN0VDnEmEIq wF9Hs3GAfqogaW1aTtrK3PwxnyCCphJZW3VpBbJp7pF8B2Ay2fibRl++xYK4emkvJZi+UGQQGxpB9+3fr4Gu6tzcUdWIR+aIzJCduCso8zUumKJ+nvuflbf0 MQjaa2EIB4WnMVTaNwZtTg==

--=_a6836d14709272c4387b47be6f69b83e
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

DON'T MISS OUR COFFEE AND CHAT WITH Jim FINANCE

Join Jim for the first of the 'coffee and chat' series hosted
by Gellibrand FEC, Williamstown SEC, and Williamstown Branch.

Time/date: 10-11:30AM, SATURDAY 28TH OCTOBER

Location: WILLIAMSTOWN COMMUNITY & EDUCATION CENTRE, 14 THOMPSON STREET,
WILLIAMSTOWN

Jim will have an open discussion with us about the Federal Liberal
Party's policy direction and other topics of interest to members.

The ticket price of $5 includes coffee.

BOOK YOUR PLACE NOW AT: https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/url?u=551&qid=78898 [1]

         

 To unsubscribe: Unsubscribe [2] 

_ Powered by Civicrm_

Links:
------
[1] https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/url?u=551&qid=78898
[2] https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=3091&qid=78898&h=3f5397f6454f5d1e

--=_a6836d14709272c4387b47be6f69b83e
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 500px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p><strong><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Don&#39;t miss our coffee and chat with Jim for Finance</span></span></strong></p>

            <p>Join Jim for the first of the &#39;coffee and chat&#39; series hosted by <u>Gellibrand FEC,</u> <u>Williamstown SEC</u>, and <u>Williamstown Branch</u>.<br />
            <br />
            Time/date: <strong>10-11:30am, Saturday 28th October</strong></p>

            <p>Location: <strong>Williamstown Community &amp; Education Centre</strong>, <strong>14 Thompson Street, Williamstown</strong></p>

            <p>Jim will have an open discussion with us about the Federal Liberal Party&#39;s policy direction and other topics of interest to members.<br />
            <br />
            The ticket price of $5 includes coffee.</p>

            <p><strong>Book your place now at</strong>:&nbsp;<a href="https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/url?u=551&amp;qid=78898" rel='nofollow'>https://www.trybooking.com/CLOUU</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
To unsubscribe: <a href="https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&amp;jid=3091&amp;qid=78898&amp;h=3f5397f6454f5d1e">Unsubscribe</a> <br/>
<br/>
<font color="maroon"><i> Powered by Civicrm</i>
<img src="https://aaa.org/drupal/civicrm/mailing/open?qid=78898" width='1' height='1' alt='' border='0'>
--=_a6836d14709272c4387b47be6f69b83e--
```

Comment: Can you post the full email with headers (within three backticks on either end so nothing gets changed)?

Comment: Also seems like this was a problem for someone else recently after upgrading to 5.66:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45727/civicrm-email-related-issue

Comment: I have added the full email in the original post. Sorry to hear someone else has had the issue.

Comment: I have also seen this, but on another 5.66 system there was no problem - I couldn't figure why one had the problem & the other didn't.  Both were Mosaico emails

Comment: Do you have a message from before the upgrade that you could compare this to?

Comment: I upgraded PHP from 7.4 (3/3/22) to PHP 8.1 (23/10/23) at the same time. I reverted back to 7.4 and it works fine! Thank you, it must be a PHP issue.
I also tried 8.0 and 8.1, same problem. Best fix is to stay with 7.4 at the moment. I will post the same email with both PHP versions (7.4 and 8.2).

Comment: I added in the 2 versions, same email.

Comment: this may be a moot point now but the civicrm versions in the Q look to be a mis-paste of the Drupal versions

Comment: Well spotted, corrected, Civicrm 5.46.2 to 5.66 (22/10/23)

Answer (score 3):

I've just been looking at the same problem.  This is caused by changing to php8.  php's internal `mail()` function has changed how it handles line endings.

The `additional_headers` should be separated with CRLF (\r\n).  The pear library ends up separating them with just LF (\n).  php7 is lenient and reformats these correctly, but php8 does not resulting in some headers (including the MIME boundary specifier) being output as a single line and therefore not correctly interpreted by mail clients.

As a quick fix, edit `vendor/pear/mail/Mail.php` and change line 225 at the end of `prepareHeaders()` from:

```
        return array($from, join($this->sep, $lines));
```

to

```
        return array($from, join("\r\n", $lines));
```

We need to get that into a proper fix.

Comment: I don't think a fix like that would be possible on a shared host.  Would reverting to PHP 7.4 be better?

Comment: Is $this->sep not "\r\n" at the top of the file though?

Comment: Andy - depends on your shared host, but if you can't edit then reverting to PHP7.4 works for now.

Comment: Lars - yes, but it is overridden by `vendor/pear/mail/Mail/mail.php` lines 84-88

Comment: I can confirm that the edit of the file fixes the issue.

Andy Clark ... this file is located here:

civicrm/vendor/pear/mail/Mail

Comment: Looks like it will be fixed upstream very soon: https://github.com/pear/Mail/pull/24

Comment: Has this been fixed in the latest versions of CiviCRM?  I just updated to PHP8 and am experiencing the same problem.  I was not smart enough to determine from the github link whether it's been fixed in the system.  Also, if not, is there anything I need to be aware of if I make the temporary fix mentioned above?

Comment: Upstream merged the fix in November but has not produced a new release - so the problem still exists in Civi.  There should not be any problems from either applying the fix in my answer here or the one in the PR.

Comment: See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4913

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your message, the problem is that there are missing line breaks in here:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0 List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:u.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org> Precedence: bulk job_id: 3086 From: "Liberals" <liberals@aaa.org> Return-Path: b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org X-CiviMail-Bounce: b.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary="=_d02e2e40878c24e4a573b81e90d7d140" Date: Fri, 27 Oct 2023 13:14:32 +1100
```

Each of these should actually be on a separate line, like so

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:u.3086.78893.b6ac1c49b1035d76@aaa.org>
...
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary="=_d02e2e40878c24e4a573b81e90d7d140"
Date: Fri, 27 Oct 2023 13:14:32 +1100
```

For this reason, the MIME boundary (`=_d02e2e40878c24e4a573b81e90d7d140`) isn't being respected in the body of the email. Why that is happening is not clear to me though.

Which version did you upgrade from? Does the same happen with bulk email (CiviMail, Mosaico) and with Send an Email?

Comment: Also, any chance you recently upgraded PHP versions?

Comment: I changed PHP from 7.4 (3/3/22) to PHP 8.1 (23/10/23). I reverted and it seems to have fixed the issue. I have edited my 1st question above and added the same email (full) in both PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to send the email?  We've most often seen this with the internal mail script (on the server).  If you can't use a third-party provider like Sendgrid or Sparkpost, you might try /sendmail as an alternative.