# PHP mail() not working with HTML messages in CiviCRM 5.68

Tags: php, mailing, html

After installing CiviCRM 5.68 if I try to send a mail formatted in HTML the mail is delivered with the name of the sender completely mispelled (e.g. b.51.429.7324bbb7c6723d5b@dbsantagiulia.org instead of comunicazioni@parrocchiasantagiulia.it), and the HTML in the message is mispelled and formatted incorrectly.
If the mail is just plain text this does not happen.
Using SMTP as mailing method this also do not happen
There is possibly a bug in the procedure calling mail() in 5.68.
I tried with PHP 7.4, 8.0 and 8.1

Here you can see two test mail sent with mail(), the first is HTML and the second plain text:

------------ HTML CORRUPTED

```
Received: from lkpkjqaz by hostingssd63.netsons.net with local (Exim 4.96.2)
    (envelope-from <b.51.429.7324bbb7c6723d5b@dbsantagiulia.org>)
To: marco.mercinelli1@gmail.com
 From: "Administrator" <progetti@parrocchiasantagiulia.eu>
 Return-Path: b.51.429.7324bbb7c6723d5b@dbsantagiulia.org
 Reply-To: "Administrator" <progetti@parrocchiasantagiulia.eu>
 Date: Tue, 02 Jan 2024 12:50:43 +0100
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary="=_751cd347c3b6fe93f79b3dd80c168c5c"
Message-Id: <E1rKdIB-00Bw7m-2g@hostingssd63.netsons.net>
From: b.51.429.7324bbb7c6723d5b@dbsantagiulia.org
Subject: TEST PHP Mail() con HTML

--=_751cd347c3b6fe93f79b3dd80c168c5c
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

TEST PHP Mail() con HTML
--=_751cd347c3b6fe93f79b3dd80c168c5c
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<p>TEST PHP Mail() con <strong>HTML</strong></p>
<img src="https://dbsantagiulia.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/open.php?q=429" width='1' height='1' alt='' border='0'>
--=_751cd347c3b6fe93f79b3dd80c168c5c--
```

------------ Plain Text - CORRECT

```
To: marco.mercinelli1@gmail.com
Subject: TEST con PHP mail() solo testo
 From: "Administrator" <progetti@parrocchiasantagiulia.eu>
 Return-Path: comunicazioni@parrocchiasantagiulia.eu
 Reply-To: "Administrator" <progetti@parrocchiasantagiulia.eu>
 Date: Tue, 02 Jan 2024 12:49:04 +0100
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Message-Id: <E1rKdGa-00BvOh-2y@hostingssd63.netsons.net>
From: comunicazioni@parrocchiasantagiulia.eu

TEST con PHP mail() solo testo
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue after recent update.  I tried making the fix in Mail.php described in this post: [link](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/html-and-email-content-and-no-graphics-or-formatting-in-emails/45791#45791).  However, it didn't work.  Just wondering if you made any progress?