# bouncing emails to virgin emails with bare CR issue

Tags: civimail

We use CiviCRM version 5.64.4 to send mail on our Drupal site.

We have recently started having lots of email bouncing from btinternet, ntlworld and virgin email addresses. the reason given is:

> Remote host said: 552 5.2.0 Message contains bare CR and is violating 822.bis section 2.3

We have been unable to trace any issues with the code in CiviCRM so far and have contacted virgin about this issue. We have not made any recent changes or updates to CiviCRM.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

While they sound quite different, I believe you are having the same problem as the person who [asked this Stack Exchange question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/45782/12).

There's a strict standard for email, but not everyone follows it down to the very last detail.  CiviCRM uses "Pear Mail", and I think you're experiencing [this bug](https://github.com/pear/Mail/pull/24).

You have a couple of options:

- If you have the choice to downgrade to PHP 7, [this Github post](https://github.com/pear/Mail/pull/24#issuecomment-1787004733) suggests that it should fix the problem.
- Pear Mail 2.0, released this week, fixes this problem.  CiviCRM [incorporated version 2.0](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29035) 2 days ago.  That puts it in the 5.71 release (March 6th, 2024).  You could wait and then upgrade.
- If you have a staff member or vendor who manages your CiviCRM, you could ask them to apply the patch right now.

If none of those are viable, please reply in the comments - I can point to this and propose that this fix be moved up into version 5.70 (February 7th, 2024).  This isn't guaranteed to be accepted though, since it gives people less time to test the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue too - as I think many UK users will have as the email domains that are enforcing this are some of the largest in the country.

Comment: Oh, and I am running PHP 7.4

Comment: pls do not use Answers as a way to say 'me too' - but perhaps you don't have the reputation yet to 'comment' (a weird requirement for StackExchange). If that is the issue then i can convert this to a comment for you